# Unable to understand this expression

Tags: bayes-theorem

[image]

I am unable to understand the above expression from the 3rd line onwards. Why is P(A|q1...qt-1)P(q1..q-1) = P(A|qt-1)P(q1..q-1)

I am not clear of the subsequent line as well

Comment: Is this from a Markov process?

Comment: I think the third line is a typo.  I think it shoulbe $P(A|q_{t-1})P(q_1, ... , q_{t-2}) = P(A|q_{t-1})P(q_{t-1}|q_{t-2})P(q_1,....,q_{t-e}) = ..... P(A|q_{t-1})P(q_{t-1}|q_{t-2})....P(q_2|q_1)P(q_1)$.

Comment: yes its about Markov process

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the Markov property (or the memoryless property) that the conditional probability of a future event only depends on the current state.

See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property) for more information about this property.